javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Am trying to setup react-native(with Android) in Windows 11 and followed all the steps mentioned in the documentation
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
But on running npm run android, I get the following error
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:370)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1357)
...
...
...

On running npx react-native doctor, I get the following result
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ● Metro - Metro Bundler is not running

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android


Tried going through the SO link, but I could not understand clearly from which link I should be downloading the certificate in my browser and add it to the truststore or why is it even required to be downloaded manually.
I tried troubleshooting by following the steps this link, but still the same error.
npm version: 10.5.2
node version: 20.9.0
react-native version: 0.74.0
java version: java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS
Can someone please help or guide me?
npm run android should run and launch the project

I solve my problem by re install the JDK using this command:
choco install -y nodejs-lts microsoft-openjdk17

and update the JAVA_HOME with new JDK location :
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-17.0.11.9-hotspot


Not yet, I tried all the steps mentioned in the React Native Docs

@cool_jb please let me know if you find any solution
